# Display result of predict in a 3 x 4 table

Tags: r, data-science, data-analysis

I have the following code in R

```
v <- c("featureA", "featureB")
newdata <- unique(data[v])
print(unique(data[v])
print(predict(model, newdata, type='response', allow.new.level = TRUE)
```

And I got the following result

```
  featureA       featureB
1    bucket_in_10_to_30 bucket_in_90_to_100
2    bucket_in_10_to_30  bucket_in_50_to_90
3     bucket_in_0_to_10  bucket_in_50_to_90
4     bucket_in_0_to_10 bucket_in_90_to_100
7    bucket_in_10_to_30  bucket_in_10_to_50
10  bucket_in_30_to_100 bucket_in_90_to_100
19    bucket_in_0_to_10   bucket_in_0_to_10
33    bucket_in_0_to_10  bucket_in_10_to_50
36  bucket_in_30_to_100  bucket_in_10_to_50
38   bucket_in_10_to_30   bucket_in_0_to_10
52  bucket_in_30_to_100   bucket_in_0_to_10
150 bucket_in_30_to_100  bucket_in_50_to_90

   1           2           3           4           7          10          19          33          36          38          52         150 
0.001920662 0.005480186 0.000961198 0.000335883 0.006311521 0.004005570 0.000620979 0.001107773 0.013100210 0.003546136 0.007382468 0.011384935
```

And I'm wondering if it's possible in R that I can reshape and directly get a 3 x 4 tables similar to this

| feature A / features B | bucket_in_90_to_100 | bucket_in_50_to_90 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bucket_in_0_to_30 | ... | ... |
| bucket_in_0_to_30 | ... | ... |

Thanks for the help!

Comment: use `table` function

Comment: Lots of code missing. What is `data`, `model`, `newdata`? None of those are defined. Provide reproducible data and actual code you have used so far to get a useful answer to your question.